# Origin of -s verbs in Norwegian and Swedish

Tags: verbs, passive, swedish, norwegian, mediopassive

(Disclaimer: I am not a linguist.)

I am learning Norwegian now, and they have some verb form when you attach *-s* to the end. It is often called passive voice (used in Present tense and in infinitive only, I guess). For example:

- *å møte* 'to meet': *vi møter* 'we meet (someone else)', *vi møtes* 'we meet (each other)'
- *å kalle* 'to call (by name)': *jeg kaller* 'I call (someone or something)', *jeg kalles* 'I am called'

I know that similar construction exists in Swedish.

I am a native Slavic speaker and we have the verbs ending with *-ся* (*się* in Polish) which have almost the same meaning. In Slavic languages, the origin of this kind of endings is clear, it means 'oneself'. For example, *учиться* 'to study' literally means *учить себя* 'to teach oneself'. So I started thinking that Norwegian and Swedish verbs maybe have some similar origins.

But does anyone know for sure?

Comment: Indeed the same: "self" (*seg*).

Comment: @user6726 but do you know some kind of trusted reference? Or, better, some article with more discussion of this?

Comment: Well, that's what people say, but people say more than they really know. https://www.britannica.com/topic/Scandinavian-languages/Phonology, http://members.unine.ch/martin.hilpert/GIGL.pdf, but I guess after looking for hard text evidence, it might just be a story. There is apparently a semantic story about medio-passives, but I haven't seen any hard evidence like old texts. I guess I'm agnostic at this point, given how hard it is to find solid evidence.

Comment: Old Norse had a passive in _-sk_, which lends credence to the theory.

Comment: in Lithuanian as well

Comment: "For example, учиться (to study) literally means учить себя (to teach oneself)" ← somewhat interestingly, Swedish has the same, "att lära sig", although this is more recent than the -s forms so it doesn't prove or disprove anything about them.

Comment: @LjL it's the translation that's funny, not the word. I'd rather compare Ger *lehren* "to teach", *lernen* "to learn" for analogy--one could wonder by the way about the n-infix in light of this question; also cp *lesen* "to read"; "study" was also a good hint, *study together* is kind of reflexive, even (and *n* can be 2nd p pl, eg. Lat *nos*; and *to-gether*, compares analoguously to *lesen*, *ver-sammeln*, *summarize*, *lego* or *ligo*). The given root is spurious for *utshiti*, I find, given the different semantics of the cognates. Hm, if *-iti* reflects \*-yeti perhaps *-ja* reflect \*-ye?

Comment: @LjL I had missed you mention "att lära sig"; I'm not sure what that translates to, regardless I suppose it might have been privative, not self-reflective, cp Ger *sicher* from "Proto-West-Germanic \*sikur, from Latin *securus*", as well as *solus*, all ultimately reflecting \*swe-; thus: "learn by myself", eventually "all on my own". I mean, it's a considerable possibility. The idiom of the infantil autodidact is notable, "look mom, no hands". If there was a pathway for Greek into Germanic, I'd even compare *auto* (from \*swe-) to *ausdenken* "think up, invent", *herausfinden* "find out", etc

Comment: "Att lära sig" is very literally "to teach (one)self", there aren't other murkier possibilities about what the *sig* may come from, since it changes depending on the actual person: *jag lär dig svenska* (I teach you Swedish), *jag lär mig svenska* (I learn Swedish, lit. I teach me/myself Swedish).

Comment: @LjL it's an anglo-saxon or low-german loan, where it was likely exclusively privative, "sick sülwst" (for himself), according to [W. Schulz, Gotica, 1909, in: Zeitschrift für Vergleichende Sprachforschung auf dem Gebiet der Indogermanischen Sprachen, 42. Bd, 3/4 H.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40847290) (cf p 319, footnote 1). There's also *laisjan sik* in the Gothic bible translating AGr *manthenein*. Hence I found the above reference. I also found doubt about Pokorny's etymology to \*leys.

Comment: @user6726 IMO there is no PIE sigmatic mediopassive, so *-s < -sk < -sik < sik* looks fairly plausible and attested in other languages.

Comment: (As ᚹᛟᛞᚨᚾᚨᛉ's answer alludes to, the -s form also works in Danish. Never thought about it until now!)

Answer (score 1):

Well, my guess is that it comes from the -sk ending in Old Norse (modern Icelandic -st ending).
As found in the famous Vǫlospá verses:

Brœðr munu BERJASK (Modern Icelandic: Bræður munu BERJAST),

Meanining "Brothers will fight EACH OTHER".

Indeed, Swedish and Norwegian are related, both come from Old Norse, which divided itself in two branches:

• Old West Norse (Icelandic, faroese, norwegian);

• and Old East Norse (Swedish, Danish);

Norwegian, however, was very influenced by Denmark for a long time, leading the language to become more similar to its East Norse cousins.

I hope it answer you well! :)

Comment: I think OP asks about the relation to Slavic (and Baltic) reflexive suffixes *-ся, -сь, -się, -s.*  Not just Scandinavian ones.

Comment: @J-mster I think they're making a comparison and a (widely held, actually) hypothesis that both may come from an original reflexive pronoun, but I don't think they're wondering whether they're actually *related* to the Slavic equivalents.